# Does Android include libraries similar to java.awt.geom?

Tags: java, android, awt

I have been browsing the reference section on Android.com and couldn't quite find the java.awt.geom library. I'm aware it isn't included exactly as it is with Java.

Specifically I'm looking for `java.awt.geom.Point2D` and `java.awt.Ellipse2D`.

Is Point (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) equivalent to Point2D in Java? Looking at the methods, they are slightly different, but is this the Android equivalent? Or is there Point2D elsewhere that I've missed?

As for `java.awt.Ellipse2D` I don't really see anything that replaces it. I see `addCircle`, `addOval`, and `addRoundedRect`. Is there Ellipse or an equivalent for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/package-summary.html: it has an OvalShape you can modify the height/width to get an ellipse.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I'll check into it. Any ideas on the `Point2D` question?

Comment: Ah, not really: on Android, most point manipulation is done with native types and not classes. Point doesn't appear to have much similarity with Point2D: there are a number of measurement methods that are simply missing. What specifically are you trying to transfer from the AWT model to Android?

Comment: I went ahead and took care of the Point2D by creating a slightly modified class of PointF. I still however can't figure out how to create the `Ellipse2D.Double()`. Can you elaborate before I create another question based on it? I'm wanting the ability to create the Ellipse based on my own `height`, `width`, and `X` and `Y coordinates`.